# Array with unknow bound

Tags: c++, arrays

The Standard sec. 8.3/4 says:

> An array bound may also be omitted when the declarator is followed by
>   an initializer (8.5).

It's ok. The following compiles fine:

```
int a[] = {1};

int main()
{
}
```

**[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8a908d7c11b5f63e)**

But 8.3/4 also says

> When several “array of” specifications are adjacent, a
>   multidimensional array is created; only the first of the constant
>   expressions that specify the bounds of the arrays may be omitted.

and the following

```
int a[][2];

int main()
{
}
```

does not compile

**[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/74989123cb4bdbc6)**

But if we add an initializer followed after the declarator:

```
int a[][1] = {{1}};

int main()
{
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d953db88b587eec5)

It works fine. Althought the Standard doesn't specify the declarator of multidimensial array have to follow by an initializer. Could you explain that?

Comment: The usual rule about omitting bounds apply. `int a[][2]` is a fine declaration in function parameters or in contexts where incomplete types are allowed. Without an initializer it declares `a` to be of an incomplete type - "array of unknown bound of array of 2 `int`".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "also" in your first quote refers to an earlier sentence:

> **In addition to** declarations in which an incomplete object type is allowed, an array bound may be omitted in some cases in the declaration of a function parameter (8.3.5). An array bound may **also** be omitted when the declarator is followed by an *initializer*

The text doesn't say so explicitly, but the intent is that *an array bound may not be omitted except for: (list of cases)*.

The code `int a[][2];` is not a declaration in which an incomplete object type is allowed (e.g. `int a[];` is also illegal). It's not in the declaration of a function parameter; nor is the declarator followed by an initializer.

So this code does not fall under any of the listed cases in which it is permitted to omit the array bound.

---

The earlier quote:

> only the first of the constant expressions that specify the bounds of the arrays may be omitted

means that bounds after the first one may not be omitted.

Comment: You mean that the rule _only the first of the constant expressions that specify the bounds of the arrays may be omitted_ for multidimensial array is general one and in additional it's restricted by the rule which requires an initializer followed by declarator. Right?

Comment: @DmitryFucintv Correct. It means you can't have types like "array of unknown bound of array of unknown bound of `int`" or "array of 3 array of unknown bound of `int`"

Answer (score 0):

You stated that

> Although the Standard doesn't specify the declarator of
>   multidimensial array have to follow by an initializer.

which is not true. Multidimensional arrays *are arrays*, so your previous cited statement from the standard about omitting array bounds also applies to them (with the added restriction).